# Combine xpath expressions

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<movies>
 <movie>
  <title>Star Wars</title>
  <genre>sci-fi</genre>
  <year>1977</year>
  <cast>
   <character cid="001">
    <role>Hero</role>
    <name>
     <first>Mark </first>
     <last>Hamill</last>
    </name>
   </character>
    <character cid="002">
               <role> Ass </role>
    <name> 
    <first> Jack</first>
    <last> Apple</last>
    </name>
   </character>
  </cast>
  <director>
    <name> 
      <first> Mark </first>
      <last> Hamill</last>
    </name>
    </director>
  <producer />
  <studio>Disney</studio>
 </movie>
 
 <movie>
  <title>Star Wars 2</title>
  <genre>sci-fi</genre>
  <year>20112</year>
  <cast>
   <character cid="002">
    <role>Hero</role>
    <name>
     <first>Mark</first>
     <last>Joseph</last>
    </name>
   </character>
  </cast>
  <director />
  <producer />
  <studio>Disney</studio>
 </movie>
 <people peoid="001">
  <name>
   <first>Mark </first>
   <last>Wei</last>
  </name>
  <name>
   <first> John</first>
   <last> Doe</last>
  </name>
 </people>
</movies>
```

I am trying to come up with an Xpath query that would give the title of all the movies where the director is also an actor. For example below, Mark Hamill appears in the cast and is also the director. I know the xpath expression to get the director name: /movies/movie/director[name]. And the xpath expression to get the name from the cast /movies/movie/cast/character[name]. Is there a way to combine the both to get the required xpath?

Comment: What version of your XPath?

Comment: It is version 2.0

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 2.0 has **Quantified Expressions**.

Check it out below.

**XPath 2.0**

```
/movies/movie[some $x in director/name/last satisfies cast/character/name/last = $x]/title
```

**Comparison on both first and last name.**

```
/movies/movie[some $x in director/name/concat(first,'|',last) satisfies cast/character/name/concat(first,'|',last) = $x]/title
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this XPath to get *title of movies where director is also an actor*:

```
//movie[cast/character/normalize-space(name)=director/normalize-space(name)]/title
```

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky , yep. It should work if name of at least one actor equals to name of at least one director